# Duplicate $1 in htaccess but it still work why?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I want to remove `.php` and `www` in my website. looking around and end up with duplicate variable `$1`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+) article.php?id=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works but can someone explain to me.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate variable `$1`?

Comment: I have 2 $1 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] and this RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]<br>

Comment: Those are two different, distinct and independant rules.

Answer (score 2):

`$1` and `$2` (and so on) are not variables for the whole file. Rather, they are references to the capture groups in the rewrite rule. (Capture groups are the parts of your regular expression that are in parentheses.)